# how to uninstall everpad?

Tags: wine, uninstall, evernote, everpad

As mentioned in title.
I realized using wine to install evernote is better than using everpad itself.  After all there are some options that everpad doesn't have.

I installed everpad through terminal as other forums only gave commands for terminal to install but when I google uninstall the program.  Quite a few mentioned about 3rd party GUI software to uninstall programs installed.

Is there a way to uninstall it without downloading more softwares?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try `sudo apt-get remove everpad`?

Comment: From https://github.com/nvbn/everpad#installation, you probably installed this using a PPA. Therefore, you should remove it by looking at http://askubuntu.com/a/310/15003.

Comment: Did you try [NixNote](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nevernote/files)? It's a java client. My evernote in wine doesn't edit notes.

Comment: @gwarah need an older version of evernote in order for it to work. So cannot install new evernotes :(

Comment: @Jos so that means whatever software we install, we can use apt-get remove (name of software) in order to remove them?

Comment: @edwinksl if what Jos suggested works, should I still do what you mentioned? (I actually did both.  What Jos mentioned first then used the --remove ppa you gave but this pretty much showed nothing in terminal.  Is it because I already removed using Jos' way?)

Comment: @Dora You can remove software installed with `apt-get install` this way, even if you needed a PPA for it. You can also remove packages this way if you downloaded a `.deb` file and installed it with `dkpg -i`, but that is slightly trickier. You cannot remove software with `apt-get` that you downloaded as a source tarball and compiled yourself. But generally, you are supposed to know what you are doing by then.

Comment: @Dora yes, you have correctly removed the package first, and then removed the PPA that you had no longer use for. If you had only removed the PPA, the software package would have been removed by force.

Comment: Re Nixnote: I use Nixnote2 on a daily basis and it hasn't disappointed me ever. It has only slightly fewer features than the Evernote client for Windows. As far as I know it should simply work.

Comment: @Dora What you have done so far is fine for everpad.

Comment: NixNote is an alternative to everpad not to evernote. On what it offers, nixnote could improve a bit in search speed.  But If evernote works fine on wine, even on an earlier version, I believe  is the best choice too.